# AWS Security Group Rules for Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a NodeJS function that creates a text file on AWS S3 bucket and sends the same file of FTP as well. It is working absolutely fine. When I converted it into lambda function it is able to create text file on S3 but fails while sending file to FTP server. My FTP Server is an EC2 instance and is using the same VPC that the lambda function is using. The security group for lambda function has the following outbound rules:
[image: SecurityGroupOutboundRules]

The inbbound rules for FTP Server are:
[image: FTPServerInboundRules]

I don't know, what am I doing wrong! As far as inbound/outbound rules are concerned, I just wanted to confirm if they look good as I am new into this AWS thing.

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @hephalump the request to send file to FTP is timing out. "Unhandled rejection Error: Timeout while connecting to server"

Comment: For IAM permissions, is your Lambda using the `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` role?

Comment: @hephalump No. It is using AdministratorAccess

Comment: @hephalump  I created a new role and assigned it AdministratorAccess.

Comment: In general I would not add any outbound rules to the Lambda function at all. I would not touch the outbound security group settings unless you really know what you are doing. By default all outbound is open. What you need to do is edit the inbound rule of the security group assigned to the FTP server, to allow anything that belongs to the Lambda's security group to have inbound access.